# image without extension is not displaying on apache

Tags: php, image, apache2

I am getting the problem that images without extension is not displaying,this issue arise on changing the server, when i shifted the code from one server to another?

Any clue what i may be missing there or a what short of things have to be enabled or disabled at my server.

Currently what i see that there is a image which displays some binary image data not the actual data.

I am adding .htaccess here that is placed at root of my project --

```
Options MultiViews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

url to view is something like -- http://mydomainsname/profileImages/41/profileImage-41-1438705718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable MultiViews [content negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html#negotiation), which makes Apache select an appropriate representation of a resource. The following directive in `.htaccess` or an appropriate `<Directory>`, `<Location>` or `<Files>` section should do that.

```
Options MultiViews
```

Comment: I have added that line to .htaccess, also placed .htacees i am using ,it shows now 403 forbidden error.

Comment: @RiggsfFolly, issue seems of apache version but I am not sure as my server support is not agree to update it to 2.4 version of apache